# a href link to tel not working if binded to ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I have call button and when clicked on, ajax register this click in the database.

I use this function on one of the servers and have no problems with it. Try to implement it in nearly exact way on another server - ajax is registering click on the button but is not initiating call on the mobile.

Any suggestion why that could be?

Some simplified code:

```
<a href="tel:123456" id='call-1'>Call</a>
<br>
<a href="tel:123456">Call without Ajax</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^=call-]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('test');
        // function containing ajax request
    });
});
```

and link to js fiddle

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/nitadesign/Ldwz1ycv/11/
```

Help appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of `e.preventDefault();` is to stop the link being followed so the JavaScript runs **instead** of the browser following the link (if you don't have `e.preventDefault();` then the JS will run *as well* as the browser following the link).